# Rigid Body, object passing through floor

Tags: physics, rigidbody

So typical rigid body simulation problem, object is passing through the floor. I am trying to set leaves to rigid bodies so when the character steps on them or pushes them they react. I have the ground set to passive and even tried making it a collision object with collision physics and then after that did not work either tried a surface force field. The leaves are set to mesh and deform, I have tried all of the settings on each feature both passive and active and still cannot figure it out. I tried applying a solidify modifier to the floor, that still did not work. I tried applying the scale to both objects, still it did not work. I really need to figure it out and if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.[image]

Edit 1: Tried flipping the normals, merging nearest vertices upon the floor after adding a simple cube and testing the simulation on the floor in question. The rigid body works in the scenario that I take a plane in a new scene and drop a cube onto it. So I figured the floor must be the problem. However, after adding the same test simulation with the cube and the simple plane into the scene that is having problems rather than in a new scene on its own. The cube just disappears and the leaves continue falling through the ground they are above. Rather than the cube falls through the ground as well, it just disappears because the plane is blocking its path from the ground. So I am running out of options to try I feel and it makes no sense to me.

Edit 2: When appended into a new scene the hill that the floor is set on appears to be bugged some how. The simple simulation worked in a new scene away from the hill. However, the same effect was still active with the hill and is not working still. I had split the mesh into the road and the hill, for material purposes and to keep weight painting easier. I used the Grasswald addon for some of the objects and then the regular particle system for other parts of it. When you hide the emitter on Grasswald it turns the object completely off in the viewport.

Edit 3: I joined the emitter, the road, and the hill back together and then tried the simulation with a cube. This time the cube launched off like a rocket. This is on standard settings that are already set aside from mesh deform for the active object. So it is progress, but still it is not working. At least it is showing to be more reactive.

Edit 4: On a separate hill that was appended into the test scene, with a new cube, the cube launched off into the air at a slower speed. When the new cube was placed high above the new hill, a hill with no material cuts or particle systems, the cube fell onto the mesh and continued to fall onto the mesh from a lesser height afterward. However this did not work for the hill in question that is having problems.

Edit 5: I have scaled the entire scene up quite a bit bringing it just a little larger than average size for everything. I have tried triangulation. The closest I came to it was getting a cube to pass down one side of the hill but anything else it would shoot up. Anything converted from a particle system it shoots down. Rigid bodies are working just fine with simple simulations. So I am going to put a bounty out. Please do not put an answer in the answer text box if you did not get it to work for yourself. Attached is the temp scene file dropbox.com/s/f8x83aglwcum90f/RBODY_Temp.zip?dl=0

I did not pack the textures. They should not matter.

Comment: I find a post with informative pictures a lot easier to understand (and to spot possible problems with the set up); you did add one screenshot, however honestly -- apart from the lack of trimming -- I can't even see where the problem is: the leaves look like they're standing on the surface! What is wrong with that configuration? Other questions include: Where is their starting position? And where's the character you're talking about? Can you try to describe your problem by means of a few effective pictures where all the rigid body actors are identifiable? Maybe even a gif!

Comment: Also, the rigid body settings from each object are something that's important to show visually! I appreciate that you've tried every possible setting, but maybe you can share the ones that you think should have worked, and we can try and figure out why they didn't. / For instance, I'm from mobile and I can't download your file right now, but are you using "mesh" as the rigid body collision boundaries? Are the collision margins small enough? Supporting highly detailed or concave objects requires a very accurate rigid body simulation: have you increased the Rigid Body World Steps and Iterations?

Comment: I have been through every setting imaginable. Right now there is no character. I was just trying to get a basic rigid body sim out of the leaves before I took the character in to make sure that it was working. I have tried every collision shape setup with both the passive and active. The leaves were converted from particles. The shot is of an old set that I had a few days ago. I deleted those not long after and tried other things. Some with rocks, other with leaves. The leaves do not extract out touching the surface. Which is why I was also going to apply rigid body to them. So that they would

Comment: Pt.2: drop. I tried dividing the ground plane into a far smaller area. I tried it all, I cannot imagine one thing that I did not. Which is why I was hoping maybe an expert could come in and figure it out hopefully. Even though I fear it to be a bug with no explanation. Just more of a reason to hope rigid bodies become a more enjoyable and stable experience in the future with Blender.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't download a 1.3 GB file to try and help you at this stage. Your question really gives too much information but not the right one (at least for me). A clear summary of what you have in your scene, with screenshots and bullet points would have helped. Sorry that you're having a poor experience with rigid bodies.

Comment: To attract more audience - describe problem shortly, simplify sample file with a problem. There is not a necessary to desrcibe all ways you failed, it could failed from many reasons so others will have to test it anyway. File is too big, Im sure you can provide much simpler (smaller) file (1.3GB is really huge). BTW I tried to download it and it failed after 100 MB.

Comment: If your issue are leaves on the road you don't have to post whole forrest.

Comment: I find a general rule that helps me a lot in life is _when you see pepe the frog run for zee hills_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I red the question, but since it's a bit confusing for me (so many steps) I sticked with title - to solve passing objects, with a [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8x83aglwcum90f/RBODY_Temp.zip?dl=0) you provided.

Start position of leaves comes from particles behaviour (they collides only in circular shape. Enabling Rigid Body to these leaves results in move ("explodes)" them down. In a Rigid Body World, there is something in your file that I didn't figured out - something that's pushing road from leaves.

So, here is a few steps to fix that:

- go to Properties Editor > Scene > **Remove Rigid Body World** and enable it again
- Set Origin > **Origin to Geometry** for the leaves and road. It protects leaves falling through the road. Origin out of geometry was always an issue.
- Road - ad Rigid Body > Passive
- Leaves - ad Rigid Body > Active and move them a bit up the road (more than set margin)
- go to Properties Editor > Physics > Rigid Body > Collisions > **Shape > Mesh**. Mainly for the road object, this can be a reason of "exploding" objects from each other. You use Convex Hull = only outer boundaries is taken into acount, since leaves are like in a valey they are pushed away.

To let leaves interact properly they should use type "Mesh" as well.

[image]

This gif is taken from your (not simplified blend, front view). I just clipped View to max 20 m, to by able even move on my private old machine.

[image]

Comment: Wow! That worked! I got it to work too! I cannot thank you enough for figuring this out! It is such a relief. If I could pay you I would, but now is just not that kind of time for me. Maybe some other time. I do really appreciate it. It means sooo much!

Comment: Good to hear it helped. I know that feeling :) just for a next time, really care to simplify scene.System for hunting an issue is still the same. First - try to recreate issue in a new file (that is what you did). Second step is to delete from issued scene element by element until an issue stops. And if you still don't see a reason, than it is a time to ask. People here are satisfied by helping to others, but use their time (and also yours) effectively. Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course. I could not find anyone who had the issue that I was having. I checked all over the web and what you found is something that it would have taken me along time to probably think of. But, again, I really do appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I see you tried many things and search (that is not the case), and I'm not asking you to find solution by your self, but you could try to delete hill and run sim, delete particle system and run sim, delete wood and run sim ... continue until issue persist. Like that we could later concentrate in searching why road and leaves (in a small simple file) are pushing each other only (or so). But I don't see much fair to let us search inside such a huge complex file that you could clean up step by step first. As I wrote already, you could get solution faster from community. Thats all. Thank you

Comment: I did do that. Obviously the solution was not deleting objects it had to do with the origins not being set properly. Well, you did not have to respond. Your responses afterwards make you sound rather incoherent and arrogant, irrelevant from the matter that solved the solution. I put out a bounty and you responded. That is something you will just have to live with.

Comment: From your reaction I don't think you understood what I'm trying to say, probably my bad english. Sorry, leave it.

Comment: Aren't you glad you helped the guy out, vklidu? ;)