# Feet pass through floor constraint at inconsistent measures

Tags: animation

I am using auto rig pro, I do not think it should make much of a difference. But, I am working in a large nature scene and scaled everything down to get higher resolution and make the environment seem bigger. It is just at the point before the camera starts shaking while it is trying to capture the object moving. I cannot ever seem to get the floor constraint to work on my character properly. One foot passes through the floor up to the ankles and then it grows more shallow as the character would step forward, meaning that the foot does not pass through the floor as far. While the other foot does the same thing but at different magnitudes. How can I fix this so that it works as it is supposed to? The size should not make much of a difference. I am most likely going to rerig my character from where it is to start animating. I noticed that it was sending the feet all out of wack when I scaled it down and took it out of the center of the grid a ways. However, the floor modifier did not work scaled up a ways at the center of the grid in the rig scene that I had set up for it, which I appended the character from into the animation scene. Any tips on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you Apply (Ctrl A) Rot and Scale to all of your characters, Rigs and Floor?

Comment: Yeah, that did not do anything either. It would be scary, but I may have to try switching to another software. I love Blender, but nothing ever works for me like it does with Blender Animation Studios. They make it sound so simple and easy. But, nothing works like it is suppose to. It has so many cool features and is so stable, can handle so many polys, but when you get to the important stuff it just fails. I am also having a problem with rigid bodies, which is a huge yikes. Combine that with the floor constrain issue and I am having serious problems I would say.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162435/rigid-body-object-passing-through-floor

Comment: Enough to leave temporarily until it is better.

Comment: Well, lucky for me. I found that I have to find the difference in the offset and so long as your feet were modeled in perfect symmetry that it will respond to the same settings of the offset and work, which is based on the distance from the grid plane. Which I found out in my rig scene. This meant that for my animation scene that I had to lower everything next to the grid as far off as it was by accident and then figure the difference from the grid based on the elevation of the hill.

Comment: Problem is, is that I need to figure out how to imply the floor modifier so that it follows the hill in its elevation. I saw the shrinkwrap modifier snaps the feet to the surface no matter its elevation, but you cannot lift the foot from off of that to make it look like it is walking. I am sure there is a constraint modifier that will work with this.  I just have not found it yet.

Comment: I think the only fix for it would be to create an edge along the floor path and extract it out and covert it into a curve and animate it based off of that to follow the path. I think it would work with motion capture, it would just constrain the movements into that path.

Comment: Sorry, my last try to direct you by advice. Keep title, summarise your description into two sentences, add image showing clearly your issue (or animation gif). Attach  simplified blend only with the issue up to 1 MB via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ if you discovered something after you asked a question - EDIT it to actual state, do not extend it if necessary. This is not a chatting room here. Why do you think you are in a monologue? Same as your mentioned "rigid body" Q with 3 downvotes. But yes, you can try bounty again.